# Compiling SDL project on Raspberry Pi

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, sdl

I am trying to build a project with make (gcc on Raspbian)

Here is the makefile (I removed some unnecessary parts):

```
objects = 3d.o Affichage.o   [...]
cflags = -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
poly : %(objects)
    gcc $(cflags) $(objects) -o poly

($objects) : types.h
[...]
```

When running Make, I got:

```
cc  -c -o Affichage.o Affichage.c
fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL.h>
```

I checked the folders, everything seems ok. SDL.h is indeed in /usr/local/include/SDL2. I tried to remove options one by one in cflags, no luck...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make told you exact command it tried to execute:

```
cc  -c -o Affichage.o Affichage.c
```

This don't have `-I` path, which is the source of an error.

You have target for your resulting executable but not for object files. Make have builtin rule to compile object files from C sources, but it isn't aware of your `cflags` variable. So far your options are:

- Define your own pattern rule

e.g:

```
%.o: %.c
   gcc $(cflags) -c $< -o $@
```

However, your `cflags` contains `-lSDL2`, which is linking flag, which should be specified only on linking phase (so technically it isn't cflag). Move it to separate variable (usually `LIBS`, which may then be enfolded into make's semi-standard `LDFLAGS`).

- Use variables that make is aware of

In that case, it is `CFLAGS`:

```
CC:=gcc
CFLAGS:=-I/usr/local/include/SDL2
LIBS:=-lSDL2
LDFLAGS:=-L/usr/local/lib $(LIBS)
objects:=3d.o Affichage.o
poly: $(objects)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
$(objects): types.h
```

The rest will be done by implicit rules.

Comment: I tried it and it works now. I must say that I don't understand everything, like why the CFLAGS doesn't seems used, and the $^, $@ too. But at least, it works so, thanks a lot!